# Changing scatter chart markers color based on a value that is not X or Y

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the markers colour in a scatter chart based on a value that is different from X or Y. The value is in the same row as the X and Y for the marker.
I've done this, but I seem to not be able to define the value area properly.
I don't really code so I might be looking at it in the wrong way...

```
Sub color_chart()

Dim chartIterator As Integer, pointIterator As Integer, _
    seriesArray() As Variant

For chartIterator = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    seriesArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
                            Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values

For pointIterator = 1 To UBound(seriesArray)
       Dim value As Range
        Set value = Worksheets("Ranking").Range("F6", "F11")
        Dim valueR As Integer
        Set valueR = value.Cells.Item(1, pointIterator)

        If valueR(pointIterator) = 0 Then
           ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
           Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
           RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ElseIf valueR(pointIterator) = 1 Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
            Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
            RGB(255, 102, 102)
        ElseIf valueR(pointIterator) = 2 Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
            Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
            RGB(255, 128, 0)
        ElseIf valueR(pointIterator) = 3 Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
            Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
            RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ElseIf valueR(pointIterator) = 4 Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
            Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
            RGB(128, 255, 0)
        ElseIf valueR(pointIterator) = 5 Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
            Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
            RGB(0, 255, 0)

       End If

Next pointIterator

Next chartIterator

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `ValueR` as an integer, so you can't use the `Set` keyword to assign its value. Further, you may want to use a `Select Case` instead of a nested `If...ElseIf...` statement, which will be more legible. I have also used a `With` block to remove some redundant calls to the chart/series/point object:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
       Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior
    Select Case ValueR
        Case Is = 0
           .Color = _
           RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case 1
            .Color = _
            RGB(255, 102, 102)
        Case 2
            .Color = _
            RGB(255, 128, 0)
        Case 3
            .Color = _
            RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Case 4
            .Color = _
            RGB(128, 255, 0)
        Case 5
            .Color = _
            RGB(0, 255, 0)
     End Select
 End With
```

Comment: Thanks, but then how do I define where to go look for the information if I can't use Set with an Integer?

Comment: Just remove hte word `Set` and you're left with a syntactically valid statement: `valueR = value.Cells.Item(1, pointIterator)`